# maven install giving error for a jar installed via artifactory

Tags: maven-3

I am deploying a particular jar named as **edireader.jar** at our artifactory based repository. In the repository browser Page for Edireader in Artifactory, following dependency is shown. The same dependency I am using inside POM.xml of the module.

```
<dependency>

<groupId>com.berryworks</groupId>

<artifactId>edireader</artifactId>

<version>4.7.3</version> 

</dependency>
```

While running maven install I am encountering following error ,

```
“com.berryworks:edireader:jar:4.7.3 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.berryworks:edireader:jar:4.7.3: Could not find artifact com.berryworks:berryworks:pom:4.7.3 in central (http://SERVER_Name:PORT/artifactory/libs-releases)”
```

And it is trying to download the jar from SERVER_Name:PORT/artifactory/libs-snapshots/com/berryworks/berryworks/4.7.3/berryworks-4.7.3.pom which seems wrong because jar resides at //SERVER_Name:PORT/artifactory/simple/libs-releases-local/com/berryworks/edireader/4.7.3/

I tried changing everything, but could not able to locate the problem.My question is why it is not picking the jar during maven install as it is present in the artifactory server.

EDIT: This is the settings.xml that I am using

```
 <profiles>
<profile>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>libs-releases</name>
      <url>http://SERVER_Name:PORT/artifactory/libs-releases</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>libs-snapshots</name>
      <url>http://SERVER_Name:PORT/artifactory/libs-snapshots</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>central</id>
      <name>plugins-releases</name>
      <url>http://SERVER_Name:PORT/artifactory/plugins-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <snapshots />
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>plugins-snapshots</name>
      <url>http://SERVER_Name:PORT/artifactory/plugins-snapshots</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <id>artifactory</id>
</profile>
```

Comment: It looks your settings.xml configuration or the configuration in Artifactory is not correct. Usually you have to configure a single url in the settings.xml file from where your artifacts are downloaded (Artifactory). This has to be configured correctly within Artifactory to have a single repo which contains all others.

Comment: @khmarbaise I do not think I have multiple urls as shown above.

Comment: First i see that your posted error messages http://SERVER_Name:PORT/artifactory/**libs-releases** that the download will done from the libs-release area of your Artifactoy but in the text you wrote SERVER_Name:PORT/artifactory/**libs-snapshots**/com/berryworks/berryworks/4.7.3/berryworks-4.7.3.pom and furthermore you give the hint that the artifact must be found in //SERVER_Name:PORT/artifactory/simple/**libs-releases-local**/com/berryworks/edireader/4.7.3/ So the question: Which one is printed out in the error message of Maven? How is the configuration in Artifactory?

Comment: @khmarbaise please check out my resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the above problem by ripping off some components created by artifactory in the POM

POM that was creating problem is as follows

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.berryworks</groupId>
  <artifactId>edireader</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>4.7.3</version>
  <name>edireader</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.berryworks</groupId>
    <artifactId>berryworks</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.3</version>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.berryworks</groupId>
      <artifactId>test-tools</artifactId>
      <version>4.7.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.berryworks</groupId>
      <artifactId>JQuantify</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>false</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.berryworks.edireader.demo.EDItoXML</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>

</project>
```

Now it is only contains the following and it is working

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.berryworks</groupId>
  <artifactId>edireader</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>4.7.3</version>
  <name>edireader</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
</project>
```