# edireader Jar not get downloaded using Maven

Tags: maven, edi

I downloaded edireader 4.7.3 from [this link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/edireader/files/). I got a Java program to read EDI file and convert it to XML file from [Here](http://edireader.sourceforge.net/).

It is working fine for me. The file gets executed and generates the XML file.

But I want to add the dependency for edireader.jar instead of adding it manually.

I added the following dependency to my pom file

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.berryworks</groupId>
      <artifactId>edireader</artifactId>
       <version>4.7.3</version> 
   </dependency>
```

But it is not downloading the JAR.

What should I add? Do I need to add any repository? If so, which one?

I have gone through [this question and tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14058713/maven-install-giving-error-for-a-jar-installed-via-artifactory). But it is not working for me.

Comment: This library doesn't seem to be mavenized, i.e. it's not a maven artifact uploaded to any public repositories. If you want to use it as dependency, you must create a maven artifact out of it (at least create a suitable pom.xml) and upload it together with a jar into a repository or just install it into your local repository.

Comment: The JAR I manually downloaded has a pom file in its MANIFEST